# Windows is removing slashes from my dates on ONE machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, date-formatting

I have two date formats in my program. On one particular machine:

- `date.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt")` is producing things like `11222013 12:0:0 AM`. (The `:0:0` is acceptable; it's a file that will normally not be read by a human.)
- `date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")` is producing things like `11222013 12:00 AM`.

My code is in C#.  The guy whose machine it is has some experience programming and was able to get the same sort of behavior with Delphi. Why are the forward slashes missing in the formatted dates? Or should I suggest he nuke and pave the offending box?

Comment: What exactly do you do to obtain `11222013 12:0:0 AM` from `M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt`?

Comment: Neither of those date formats will produce the output you indicate they are, so you're going to need to provide much more information. Both of them include the `/` date separator, but neither output does, and that's just not how it works. Either your format isn't what you say it is, or your output isn't what you indicate. (How are you setting  "two date formats in the system"? Windows only allows one date format to be active.)

Comment: @Joker_vD A perfectly ordinary <Date Variable>.toString(DateFormat).  It works fine on every other computer that's run the code.

Comment: @KenWhite I know they shouldn't!  I can't imagine what's becoming of my /'s.  Those are actual format strings being used to convert the dates.

Comment: @KendallFrey The problem?  No /s in the dates!

Comment: @Loren Pechtel: You're omitting something. Most likely the date format string you've given to the method.

Comment: What is the output of: "Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator);"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), an unquoted slash is just a placeholder for the culture-specific [`DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) (which can be strings like "-" and ".", depending on the culture). If on that other machine, someone has customized the Windows region settings and removed the separators from the short date format, then `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` will be an empty string, and your formatted dates will lack slashes.

To force the use of slashes, surround the slashes with quotes in your format strings, or pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the formatting methods. For example, you could write

```
date.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy h:m:s tt")
```

or

```
date.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` would be a better choice if you're expecting ":" and AM/PM in your formatted times instead of localized values like "." and Mo Mosong/Mo Maitseboeng (South Africa).

Comment: That was it.  I had no idea the / was subject to replacement.